# Best to move my transaction backups one way when they are created

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-transfer

I have read and tried a number of sync options, but none of them meet my exact needs.  What I am doing:

- I move .trn files from one Windows 2008 server to another in another location
- I need the transfer to be secure (currently SFTP)
- The .trn files get created every 30 minutes, there are 500+ of them
- The directory these go to on the source has many files 
       (7 days * 500 catalogs * 48 = 170,000+)
- I am currently moving based on the archive flag
       SyncBack takes a long time just to scan for changes

What I want:
  - I want a process that will pickup new files as they are created and move them to the destinaton
  - I want this to happen near real time and not on a schedule
  - I do not want the process slowed by the number of total files

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx).

EDIT:

Oops. Scratch that. Robocopy doesn't do secure file transfer.